# create sub from data frame in R

Tags: row, subset, multiple-columns

How to select some column and rows all together from data frame using R studio ?

I tried to use example: column name [1:10] but it gives me rows numbers not the actual row info , the results is that I see column names in the rows I see numbers from 1 to 10 .